# Can you freeze a Pecan Pie?

Tags: storage-method, freezing, pie

Can/should I freeze a pecan pie I plan to use 7 days after making?

Answer (score 3):

You sure can. You should wrap it tightly in plastic wrap, aluminum foil, and place it in a freezer bag. It will be best quality for 1-2 months.

It's important to wrap it *tightly* to minimize ice crystals & freezer burn.

Source: [StillTasty](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17949)