# Can you freeze a tomato pie?

Tags: baking

Can I freeze a tomato pie? If so, is it better to do this before or after I bake it?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I am not sure if every pie is the same, but [this answers for pecan pie](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10306/31372).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to freeze it before baking.
When baking the pie some of the ingredients release their flavors, and those can be lost during the freeze. For that reason - the pie would probably preserve more taste if frozen unbaked (But will take more time to be ready for eating after removing from freezer)